# Animal Crossing New Leaf Random Time?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I play animal crossing new leaf all the time, but for some reason, my game changed from october 2018 to september 2018. i lost an animal for something I didn’t change, has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: Did you check if the time was also changed on your 3DS ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that happened to my friend, if you haven't played in a while your time may have jumped forward or back. Or you maybe messed with your time to time travel before and never fixed it.